# Why is this regex /^(?:(?:^(like)(ly|s)?$))/imatching the word alike?

Tags: regex

I am trying to match forms of the word like.  Specifically, I want a regular expression that matches

- like
- likely
- likes

This is my current regular expression.

```
/^(?:(?:^(like)(ly|s)?$))/i
```

When I run it in my javascript console, it matches the three above words.  However, for some reason it also matches the word "alike."  Specifically, it matches the 'like' part of alike.  I put in the \b at the beginning to make certain that it *didn't* match alike.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: `(like)*` should be `like`.

Comment: Nope, it matches the empty string at the start of *alike*. Your pattern will match *everything*, as it matches the empty string.

Comment: Sorry, I put in the wrong regular expression.  I've now replaced it with the one I'm actually using.

Comment: [It seems *alike* is not matched](https://regex101.com/r/uC8dZ2/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your regex to:

```
/\blike(?:ly|s)?\b/i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gX7wY0/4)

Problem in your regex is use of `(like)*` which will make it match an empty string also.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the asterisk in the middle, use the following Regex.

```
(?:^(like)(ly|s)?$)
```

[See](http://regexr.com/3bku0) it in action.